# isolate input in a module shiny when using insert ui

Tags: shiny, module

I'd like to create several ui which use an input parameter. The problem is that the new UI created are still reacting to the input even when I put an isolate()

The right behaviour would give a custom UI created and isolated from the new inputs coming from the selectInput()[image]
For instance I'd like a first UI with the year 2019 selected and second UI with the year 2020.
Here we can see that adding 2020 will change in each UI which is wrong.

```r
library(shiny)
customplotUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(id=ns("sidebarpanel"),
                 actionButton(ns("add"),label = "Add"),
                 selectInput(inputId=ns("years"),label="Year :", choices = c(2019,2020),selected = 2019, multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(div(id=ns("placeholder"))
              )
  )
}
customplot <- function(input,output,session){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    data <- data.frame(year=c(2019,2020),value=c("mtcars2019","mtcars2020"))
    data[data$year %in% input$years,]})
  
  
  ctn <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  Id <- reactive({
    function(id){
      paste0(id, ctn())
    }
  })
  IdNS <- reactive({
    function(id){
      ns(paste0(id, ctn()))
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    ctn(ctn() + 1)
    print(Id()('div'))
    
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = div(
        id = Id()('div'),
        verbatimTextOutput(IdNS()('chart'))
        )
      )
    id <- Id()('chart')
      output[[id]] <- renderPrint({
        data <- data.frame(year=c(2019,2020),value=c("mtcars2019","mtcars2020"))
        #data[data$year %in% isolate(input$years),]
        data[data$year %in% input$years,]
      })
  })
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  customplotUI(id="customplot")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(customplot,id="customplot",session=session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish, but when I run the code, using the commented line with `isolate` seems to work as intended.

[image]

I'm guessing that in creating the minimal reprex (thank you for doing this btw!), you might have gone a little too minimal and removed another reactive that updates `data`. If you are trying to have the individual UI elements update based on some other input but keep the same filtering scheme, you need to capture the current value of `input$years` outside of the `renderPrint` statement.

Here you can see the subset of rows is unchanged, but the last column updates based on input box:

```
...
    id <- Id()('chart')
    targetYears <- input$years
    
    output[[id]] <- renderPrint({
      data <- data.frame(year=c(2019,2020),
                         value=c("mtcars2019","mtcars2020"), 
                         yrInput = paste(input$years, collapse =" "))
      data[data$year %in% targetYears, ]
...
```

[image]

`isolate` only prevents a change in the reactive from triggering an update. If the update is triggered by something else, the current/updated value of the reactive is still used. Through the wonders of R's scoping rules, by capturing the value of `input$years` in non-reactive variable, `targetYears`, outside of the `renderPrint` call and then using that in the `renderPrint` expression it will always use the the value of the input when `output[[id]]` was created. The `isolate` is not needed as you are using `observeEvent` which will prevent the observer from executing when you change the input.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the second behaviour you mentionned. Don't know why I did't get this idea before haha. Many thanks for the detailed explanation!